# Microsoft Edge's "Improved copy and paste of URLs" feature in other browsers

Tags: web-browser, microsoft-edge

There is a feature in Microsoft Edge browser described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/improved-copy-and-paste-of-urls-in-microsoft-edge-d3bd3956-603a-0033-1fbc-9588a30645b4) which makes copied and pasted URLs formatted, not in a plain text. For example, when you go to the Wikipedia's homepage and copy its URL and paste it in OneNote, it will look like [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/), not like *https://www.wikipedia.org/*.

Are there any other browsers, which also support this feature or perhaps any extensions to such browser? Personally, I am not a big fan of Microsoft Edge, but this feature comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TextLinkyTool](https://github.com/Yukisama/TextLinkyTool), which is available for Firefox and Chrome. It hooks into the context menu, so when you right-click a link you can select the format to copy in. There are some pre-configured formats, but you can even define your own.

Examples of formats:

- Markdown (as used here, i.e. `[title](url)`)
- HTML (e.g. `<a href='url'>title</a>`, but you could also edit the format to include other attributes, like `<a href='url' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>title</a>`
- just the title
- just the URL
- BBCode (for forums using it)

I'm using this extension for many years now and am quite happy with it. Definitely can recommend.

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful when posting links to forums. However, I usually paste URLs into Microsoft OneNote. With Edge, the title of the page gets displayed as text with a link address under the hood. I tried using the tool you suggested for the same results but to no avail. Do you perhaps know how to achieve that with this tool?

Comment: I rather avoid MS products (running solely on Linux since around 2000, got rid of Windows long before that), so I unfortunately cannot help you with that. I can only vaguely guess they might use "Rich Text" for that. The addon allows you to create your own formats – but I've no idea how to define RT. Maybe our sister site can help out with that: [What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2850575/2533433)